# Win7 PC Shutdown during Update - Driver/Chipset Issues?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

**--UPDATE 1--**

Purchased a brand new USB Wifi Adapter, installed its driver and has exact same problem error code 31. Obviously it's a Windows 7 issue. Is it possible to repair this without a complete reinstall?

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Okay, so my friend's desktop PC started up at 3am whilst he was sleeping. He woke up and forced it to shut down during an update not realising the implications this could cause. The following day he started his PC up and windows began repairing itself. However once the computer loaded into Windows he has what appears to be driver issues in `Device Manager`. This is shown below.

[image: Image Link]

Excuse the German, I don't think it's relevant anyway. We've removed the `Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11N PCI-E NIC` driver, restarted the system, and installed the following driver: `2007.12.0419.2013_ISS_1.00.0212.L`. However, it doesn't matter if this driver is installed using the setup.exe **or** if it's installed via the manual method of locating the driver files. We keep getting the following error:

> This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the
>   drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

Suggestions to fix this error code revolve around the re-install of the driver, but we've done this many times ensuring a full system restart each time. Is there something we're missing?

Uninstallation of drivers were done in `Device Manager`, and as I've mentioned, we've tried re-installing the drivers. The motherboard only identifies itself as `LENOVO`. Here's the system specs if they're relevant:

- Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium m 64-Bit SP1
- CPU: Intel Core i7 3770 @ 3.40GHz
- RAM: 8 GB Dual-Channel
- Motherboard: LENOVO (Bios version E8KT24AUS)
- Chipset: Z75
- Graphics: 2048MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 7500 Series (MSI)
- Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN
- Computer Model:

Solutions tried:

- Ethernet cable, still not recognised.
- Installation of new driver, error code 31.
- System Restore, none available.
- Driver roll back, none available.

We can't get a direct internet access to update all drivers or windows, so it's becoming a very slow and annoying process. However he does have a laptop he can access the internet with and transfer files to and from his desktop using USB.

Could this possibly be a chipset issue? I find it strange that the USB ports are detected as not having installed properly but these function ok. As this issue only happened after the failed update I'm convinced it's simply a software issue and not hardware related. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the update corrupted the driver, this is why i always disable windows update.
If you have an android phone, hook it up to the pc with an usb cable and enable usb tethering on the phone, it's a quick and dirty internet access.
Try removing the driver from the available driver list (can be found in mcc, i think).

Comment: Please see update, it appears to be a windows issue :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be a problem with Windows. I wasn't able to repair windows and instead used the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) in order to download Windows 10 on another machine and upgrade the Widnows 7 Home Premium - effectively re-installing windows files **but keeping personal files & programs.** This solved *all* driver issues.

Just thought I'd post this answer to help others out in the future.